# What is the Server URL of my Android Apk?

Tags: android, server, apk, android-volley

I am using PHP JSON Volley for authenticating my login activity .Currently i am giving the localhost and IP address to test my application (Please find my code below). But when the APK is generated , what is the URL that should be given ? Kindly guide.

```
      public class LoginActivitywithConnection extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "LoginActivitywithConnection";
        private Button btnLogin;
        private Button btnLinkToRegister;
        private EditText usernameEditText;
        private EditText inputPassword;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private SessionManager session;
        private DbHandler db;
        String userType;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Log.i(TAG, "entered");
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    Bundle data = i.getExtras();
    if (data != null) {
        String buttonClicked = data.getString("ButtonClicked");
        if (buttonClicked.equals("asha")) {
            userType = "asha";
        } else if (buttonClicked.equals("anm")) {
            userType = "anm";
        } else if (buttonClicked.equals("doc")) {
            userType = "doc";
        } else if (buttonClicked.equals("sdm")) {
            userType = "sdm";
        }
    }


    usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

}


public void loginCLick(View view) throws SocketException {
    Log.i(TAG, "entered login");
    String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String ashaphno = username;
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    // Check for empty data in the form
    if (!ashaphno.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
        chkStatus();
        // login user
        checkLogin(ashaphno, password);

        Log.i(TAG, "username(ashaphone)" + username);

        Intent i;

    }
}


// Link to Register Screen
public void clickregister(View view) {


    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            AshaRegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}


/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 */
public void checkLogin(final String ashaphno, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    Log.i(TAG, "loginactivity" + userType);
                    if (userType.equals("asha")) {
                        JSONObject asha = jsonObject.getJSONObject("asha");
                        String username = asha.getString("AshaUsername");
                        String phone = asha.getString("Ashaphno");

                        if (username.equals(phone)) {
                            // Launch main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivitywithConnection.this,
                                    LoginOpeningPageAsha.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("username", ashaphno);
                            intent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                    } else if
                    (userType.equals("anm")) {
                        Intent i;
                        i = new Intent(LoginActivitywithConnection.this, LoginOpeningPageANM.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();

                        b.putString("username", ashaphno);
                        i.putExtras(b);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "error" +
                            errorMsg);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());

            String message = null;
            if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String erroridentifier = handleServerError(volleyError, getApplicationContext());
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Erroridentifier: " + erroridentifier);
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("AshaUsername", ashaphno);
            params.put("ASHApwd", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    DefaultRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);


    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Constants Class :

```
    public class Constants {

    private static final String ROOT_URL ="http://192.168.43.6/Android/v1/";
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = ROOT_URL+"ashaLogin.php";


}
```

When this apk is downloaded by a user , what will be the server URL(not local) ?

Answer (score 1):

I will be the same URL server, if you what to make work the apk wherever it execute, you should create a public server. Azure, Google, etc, or an server with public IP.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using some localhost and serving your PHP code to implement authentication, before releasing your android app into stores like GooglePlay you should first deploy your backend code into some servers like Azure, Digital ocean,... and after deployment and running your backend code on some server you should enter your backend's URL into your app. also I recommend you using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for your networking stuff it will decrease much of stuff you should deal with.

Comment: Thank you so much .will look into Retrofit 